# Decoding Complex Nested JSON in Swift 4 Lots of Errors

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I am trying to model this nested JSON here into a readable object in Swift, but I am running into lots of unnecessary issues. I want to load the Bible into my app from JSON so I can play with it from a data perspective. Here is my code:

```
struct Bible: Codable {
    var book: String
    var chapters: [Chapter]
}
struct Chapter: Codable {
    var chapter: String
    var verses: [Verse]
}
struct Verse: Codable {
    var verse: [String:String]
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var bible: Bible?
    var myText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let urlString = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aruljohn/Bible-kjv/master/Genesis.json"
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
               parse(json: data)
            }
        }
    }//end of viewDidLoad

    func parse(json: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let jsonBible = try? decoder.decode(Bible.self, from: json) {
            bible = jsonBible.self
            bible?.book = jsonBible.book
        }
        myText = bible!.book
        print(myText)
    }//end of parse
}
```

Here is a small sample of the JSON:

```
{
"book":"Genesis",
"chapters":[
{
"chapter":"1",
"verses":[
{
"1":"In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth."
},
{
"2":"And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters."
},
{
"3":"And God said, Let there be light: and there was light."
},
{
"4":"And God saw the light, that it was good: and God divided the light from the darkness."
},
{
"5":"And God called the light Day, and the darkness he called Night. And the evening and the morning were the first day."
},
{
"6":"And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters, and let it divide the waters from the waters."
},
{
"7":"And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it was so."
},
```

(Excuse the readability)

First of all the model I have will not let me access the data I want to.
And currently now Swift isn't reading one of my fields in the struct even though it's right there. It was giving me all types of errors so I commented out the chapters field in the Bible struct. I uncomment it and now Swift acts like it's not there, and now I can't access that either.

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: `try? something`: DON'T. Instead, write:` do { ... try something ... } catch { print("Error: \(error)") }`. Error usually gives interesting informations about what failed, tips to fix. Read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
var verses: [Verse]
```

With

```
var verses: [[String:String]]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Bible
struct Bible: Codable {
    let book: String
    let chapters: [Chapter]
}

// MARK: - Chapter
struct Chapter: Codable {
    let chapter: String
    let verses: [[String: String]]
}
```

And to decode the JSON I used this:

```
func fetchBible() {
    let urlString = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aruljohn/Bible-kjv/master/Genesis.json"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("Not url")
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        guard let bible = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Bible.self, from: data) else {
            print("Error decoding JSON")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(bible)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```